# SQL Conditional Date Filters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, conditional-statements

I have an SQL stored procedure in which I want different filters to apply depending on the value of two control parameters @FilterOption, @DateFilterOption. The first one determines if a field equals, starts with or contains and is working ok. The second one is used to determine if a date equals , is greater than, or less than and also works ok. The problem is that they don't work together.

Two other parameters @FilterValue and @DateFilterValue are the actual values used for filtering. If I use all AND's for the date options instead of OR's then it dosn't work correctly, so is there a better way to code the date options in the HAVING CLAUSE.

Thanks
CM

```
create Procedure [dbo].[SelectPagedData]
(
    @FilterValue NVARCHAR(50),
    @CurrentPage INT,
    @PageSize INT,
    @TotalRecords INT OUTPUT,
    @OrderField INT,
    @FilterOption INT,
    @DateFilterOption INT,
    @DateFilterValue DATE
)

As

--FilterOption
--0=none
--1=CustomerStartsWith,
--2=CustomerContains,
--3=CreatedByStartsWith,
--4=CreatedByContains

--@DateFilterOption
--0=none
--1=CreatedByEquals,
--2=CreatedByGreaterThan,
--3=CreatedByLessThan,
--4=ModifiedOnEquals,
--5=ModifiedOnGreaterThan,
--6=ModifiedOnLessThan

-- Turn off count return.
Set NoCount On

-- Declare variables.
Declare @FirstRec int
Declare @LastRec int

-- Initialize variables.
Set @FirstRec = (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize
Set @LastRec = (@CurrentPage * @PageSize + 1)

IF @DateFilterOption = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @DateFilterValue = '1900-01-01' 
END

IF @FilterOption = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @FilterValue = 1 
END

IF @FilterOption = 1 OR @FilterOption = 3
BEGIN
    SET @FilterValue = @FilterValue + '%' 
END

IF @FilterOption = 2 OR @FilterOption = 4
BEGIN
    SET @FilterValue = '%' + @FilterValue + '%' 
END

PRINT @FilterValue

Create Table #TempTable
(
    NewQuoteID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    QuoteID INT,
    GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    EquipmentID INT, 
    QuoteName NVARCHAR(50),
    AccountNumber NVARCHAR(50),
    ADName NCHAR(10),
    CreatedOn DATETIME,
    LastModifiedOn DATETIME,
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(100),
    EquipmentName NVARCHAR(200),
    Total DECIMAL(18,2)
)

--Fill the temp table
Insert INTO #TempTable 
(
    QuoteID,
    GUID,
    EquipmentID,
    QuoteName,
    AccountNumber,
    ADName,
    CreatedOn,
    LastModifiedOn,
    CustomerName,
    EquipmentName,
    Total
)
SELECT Q.QuoteID, Q.GUID, Q.EquipmentID, Q.QuoteName, Q.AccountNumber, Q.ADName, Q.CreatedOn, 
  Q.LastModifiedOn, C.CustomerName, E.EquipmentName, SUM(QD.Amount) Total
FROM 
    Quotes Q
JOIN
    Customers C
ON Q.AccountNumber = C.AccountNumber
JOIN
    Equipment E
ON E.EquipmentID = Q.EquipmentID
JOIN
    QuoteDetails QD
ON QD.GUID = Q.GUID
GROUP BY q.QuoteID, Q.GUID, Q.EquipmentID, Q.QuoteName, Q.AccountNumber, Q.ADName,
 Q.LastModifiedOn, Q.CreatedOn,C.CustomerName, E.EquipmentName
HAVING
    (CASE @FilterOption 
    WHEN 0 THEN '1'
    WHEN 1 THEN C.CustomerName 
    WHEN 2 THEN C.CustomerName 
    WHEN 3 THEN Q.ADName 
    WHEN 4 THEN Q.ADName 
    END) LIKE @FilterValue 
 AND
(@DateFilterOption = 0 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) > @DateFilterValue)  
OR
(@DateFilterOption = 1 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) = @DateFilterValue)  
OR
 (@DateFilterOption = 2 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) > @DateFilterValue)  
OR
 (@DateFilterOption = 3 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) < @DateFilterValue)  
OR
(@DateFilterOption = 4 AND CONVERT(date, Q.LastModifiedOn,101) = @DateFilterValue)  
OR
(@DateFilterOption = 5 AND CONVERT(date, Q.LastModifiedOn,101) > @DateFilterValue)  
OR
(@DateFilterOption = 6 AND CONVERT(date, Q.LastModifiedOn,101) < @DateFilterValue)  
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 0 THEN [QuoteName] END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 1 THEN [QuoteName] END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 2 THEN CreatedOn END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 3 THEN CreatedOn END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 4 THEN LastModifiedOn END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 5 THEN LastModifiedOn END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 6 THEN CustomerName END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 7 THEN CustomerName END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 8 THEN ADName END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 9 THEN ADName END DESC

--Select one page of data based on the record numbers above
Select 
    QuoteID,
    GUID,
    EquipmentID,
    QuoteName,
    AccountNumber,
    ADName,
    CreatedOn,
    LastModifiedOn,
    CustomerName,
    EquipmentName,
    Total
From 
    #TempTable
Where 
    NewQuoteID > @FirstRec 
And 
    NewQuoteID < @LastRec
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 0 THEN [QuoteName] END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 1 THEN [QuoteName] END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 2 THEN CreatedOn END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 3 THEN CreatedOn END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 4 THEN LastModifiedOn END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 5 THEN LastModifiedOn END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 6 THEN CustomerName END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 7 THEN CustomerName END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 8 THEN ADName END,
    CASE WHEN @OrderField = 9 THEN ADName END DESC

SELECT 
    @TotalRecords = COUNT(*)
FROM 
   #TempTable
```

Comment: Ca you elaborate your question more? it seems there is a huge messup, I mean your problem is not clear

Comment: Hi sorry if not clear, I am having trouble with the date code: (@DateFilterOption = 1 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) = @DateFilterValue). for example if I search for a customer name beginning with 'T' and created on a specific date, I get records returned with the correct date but also with customers begnning with other letters. If I change the ORs to ANDs I get no records returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just your parentheses.  Try changing the `having` clause to:

```
HAVING (CASE @FilterOption 
            WHEN 0 THEN '1'
            WHEN 1 THEN C.CustomerName 
            WHEN 2 THEN C.CustomerName 
            WHEN 3 THEN Q.ADName 
            WHEN 4 THEN Q.ADName 
        END) LIKE @FilterValue AND
       ((@DateFilterOption = 0 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) > @DateFilterValue) OR
        (@DateFilterOption = 1 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) = @DateFilterValue) OR
        (@DateFilterOption = 2 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) > @DateFilterValue) OR
        (@DateFilterOption = 3 AND CONVERT(date, Q.CreatedOn,101) < @DateFilterValue) OR
        (@DateFilterOption = 4 AND CONVERT(date, Q.LastModifiedOn,101) = @DateFilterValue) OR
        (@DateFilterOption = 5 AND CONVERT(date, Q.LastModifiedOn,101) > @DateFilterValue) OR
        (@DateFilterOption = 6 AND CONVERT(date, Q.LastModifiedOn,101) < @DateFilterValue)
       )
```

Two additional comments.  First, doing the filtering in a `where` clause is usually more efficient, because it reduces the volume of data needed for the aggregation.  Second, you don't need to convert date values that are stored as dates.  And, it is a bad idea to store dates as strings.  So, the various dates should already be dates.  If they are `datetime` and you just want to convert them to `date`, remove the third argument to `convert()`.  That is used for converting strings to dates.  (Actually, I always use `cast(col as date)` in that case, but either `cast()` or `convert()` is fine.)

Comment: Thanks very much, this works just as I wanted. Regards your comments, the database has datetime fields as I want to show this detail in the UI. But I only want to search by date, so is the best way to do this using cast(Q.CreatedOn as date) rather than using convert?

Comment: @CodeMechanic . . . As I tried to explain, `cast()` and `convert()` (without the third argument) are equivalent.  You should just remove the `101` argument from `convert()`.  With the argument, I'm not sure what SQL Server does, but it might convert the column to a string and then convert it back to a date format.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, much appreciated, CM